# is it possible to use activeX controls with win32 Aplications?

Tags: winapi, mfc, activex

I'm coding my **Win32 application** with **MFC shared DLL** and I was trying to use **ActiveX controls** on it , is that possible? or I'm just wasting my time?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it can get finicky. Hard to say anything else without a more specific question.

Comment: @mnistic thanks for comment ,can you direct me to some documents or tutorial or any kind of way to get some knowledge about using activex controls on Win32 application with MFC shared DLL?

Comment: @EricsonGomes this has nothing to do with MFC. Plenty of non-MFC Windows apps host ActiveX controls.

Comment: and this plenty of non-MFC windows app would be? I need a root to start learning any kind of way to develop in c++ to windows , could u @RemyLebeau give me some light?

Comment: @EricsonGomes MSDN has all the information you need. ActiveX is a large topic, plenty of information on it

Comment: ok,i'll go search in MSDN documentation @RemyLebeau, thanks for reply.

Comment: If you are serious about laying a solid foundation, start with Don Box' [Essential COM](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201634465). If you don't want to have to guess about every single line of code you are going to write, this is absolutely mandatory reading.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a new MFC project, make sure you activate ActiveX support (example using VS2008):

[image]

Often you want to use an ActiveX control from within a dialog window. Right click on the dialog in the designer view and select 'Insert ActiveX control' and select the ActiveX you want:

[image]

If you want to freely embed an ActiveX control outside a dialog, there is an ATL wrapper for MFC. But it's a bit more tricky and would look like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "atlbase.h"
#include "oleidl.h"
#include "comdef.h"

...
...

    AtlAxWinInit(); 
    pPluginWnd = new CAxWindow();
    CRect r = GetParent()->GetClientRect();
    if (!pPluginWnd->Create(GetParent()->m_hWnd, r, "ActiveX Plugin Window", WS_VISIBLE 
        | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL)))
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Couldn't create the ActiveX host window");
        return;
    }

    LPUNKNOWN pUnk;
    pPluginWnd->QueryControl(&pUnk);
    IDispatch *spDispatch; 
    HRESULT hRes = pUnk->QueryInterface(__uuidof(spDispatch), (void **) &spDispatch);   
    if (hRes != S_OK)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Couldn't query the ActiveX interface");
        return;
    }

    // get a method called 'Init' in the ActiveX to pass a long integer parameter to it
    long nMyValueToPass;
    DISPID dispid;
    OLECHAR FAR szMember[5];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, "Init", -1, szMember, 5);
    OLECHAR FAR *pszMember = szMember;
    DISPPARAMS dispparams = { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 };
    VARIANT vRet;
    COleVariant vParam(nMyValueToPass,VT_I4);
    EXCEPINFO excepinfo;
    UINT nArgErr;
    dispparams.rgvarg = (LPVARIANT)vParam;
    dispparams.cArgs = 1;
    dispparams.cNamedArgs = 0;

    hRes = spDispatch->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &pszMember, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid);
    if (hRes != S_OK)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Init method couldn't be found in ActiveX control");
        return;
    }

    // call the Init method
    hRes = spDispatch->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, 
        DISPATCH_METHOD, &dispparams, &vRet, &excepinfo, &nArgErr);
```

Comment: It's not strictly required to enable ActiveX support in the New Project wizard. You can still add ActiveX controls to a project that wasn't created with this option enabled. It doesn't perform any sort of magic; it just adds code. Besides that, calling an ActiveX control through its `IDispatch` interface from C++ is the least common use case of an ActiveX control. And the implementation is *very* confusing. I mean, what's the rationale for calling `MultiByteToWideChar` over using a `L"Init"` string literal? Or the happy mixture of RAII wrappers and naked `VARIANT`'s?

Comment: *sigh* sorry, I think, I told you before: I'm not perect. But the details of my specific implementation are of no concern here and only should sketch the path to go. It's indeed historic non-unicode source of mine from VS 6 times or before, modified to illustrate, but not optimized. And yes, using ActiveX controls in dialogs is the usual use case, which I tried to express with the adverb 'often'. But I just was afraid of a nitpicker, stating that my answer is rubbish, because the question did not specify that the ActiveX has to be used in a dialog, thus the answer was not general enough.

Comment: There's no nitpicking in pointing out, that going through the `IDispatch` interface of an ActiveX control from C++ is the least common use case. Just query for a statically typed interface, and condense the 25+ lines of `IDispatch` madness into a single call. Statically checked by your compiler. I don't know what any of this has to do with dialogs.