# Can a DLL created from Visual C# 2019 be used in MFC 6.0?

Tags: c#, dll, mfc

I have written a simple web service get function using Visual C# 2019 (.NET Framework) and compile it as DLL.

```
namespace Transporter
{
    public class transport
    {
        private Int32 returnCode;
        private string responseBody;

        private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public Int32 StartRequest(string baseAddress, string content, string token, string userName, string password)
        {
            var t = Task.Run(() => postRequest(baseAddress, content, token, userName, password));
            t.Wait();
            
            responseBody = t.Result;

            return returnCode;
        }

        private async Task<string> postRequest(string baseAddress, string content, string token, string userName, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", token);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("username", userName);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("password", password);

                    returnCode = 0;
                    responseBody = "";
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(baseAddress, content))
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                returnCode = 99;
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the DLL in an application written with MFC 6.0. I have tried dllimport and loadlibrary, but not success.

```
typedef int32 (CALLBACK* LPSTARTREQUEST)(CString, CString, CString, CString, CString);
HINSTANCE hinstDLL;                 // Handle to DLL
LPSTARTREQUEST lpStartRequest;      // Function pointer
int32 intReturnCode;                // Return code from DLL function
CString cstrBaseAddress, cstrContent, cstrToken, cstrUserName, cstrPassword;
hinstDLL = LoadLibrary("Transporter.dll");
if (hinstDLL != NULL)
{
    lpStartRequest = (LPSTARTREQUEST)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "StartRequest");
    if (!lpStartRequest)
    {
        // handle the error
        return "error";
    }
    else
    {
        // call the function
        intReturnCode = lpStartRequest(cstrBaseAddress, cstrContent, cstrToken, cstrUserName, cstrPassword);
    }
    FreeLibrary(hinstDLL);
}
```

Can anyone tell me if this is actually possible?
Thanks.

Comment: "Visual C# 2019" tells us less than you might think. Is the DLL .NET Framework, .NET Standard, or .NET Core / .NET 5?

Comment: MFC and VC++ 6 aside, it's not clear from the question how you would use the C# assembly with "*dllimport and loadlibrary*" from *any* unmanaged C++ app, even one created with the same VS 2019.

Comment: @Llama using .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: @Ives Open a [developer command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2019#developer-command-prompt) and run `dumpbin /exports Transporter.dll`. Do you see `StartRequest` listed there? If not, then there is no such export that you can call, regardless of what version of VC++ you write the unmanaged code in. If you *do* see it, then show the relevant C# code, since exporting plain C APIs is not natively supported in .NET.

Comment: It's completely unlikely for a function written in C# to accept arguments of type `CString` by value. And that's ignoring, that `CString` isn't even a type, but a macro.

Comment: @dxiv I have register the dll actually, but still dumpbin shows no such file.

Comment: @IInspectable I can only use reference for string?

Comment: No. You cannot have a **native** type in a managed interface, not by value and not by reference. This is the inverse of P/Invoke, where the system covers up for all your mistakes. This is where you have to specify the correct type, and there's not system to help you.

Comment: @Ives Registration has nothing to do with it. You need to either `cd` to the directory where `Transporter.dll` resides before running `dumpbin`, or pass the full path on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call .NET functions in the C# class library directly from your MFC code. You need to use COM instead of the DLL managing functions win32 provides. E.g. insted of `LoadLibrary()` you would use COM's `IDispatch::QueryInterface()` and instead of `GetProcAddress()` you would call `IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames()` to retrieve the entrypoint for the function, which you would then call using `IDispatch::Invoke()`.

There are some necessary preparations before you can do so:

- In your .NET class library switch on 'Register for COM interoperability' on the build tab of the project properties.
- Also in the properties it's recommended to 'Sign the assembly'. This is important, if you want to provide future updates for the class library.

For COM to work, you need to provide an uuid. E.g. in the file 'UserControl1.Designer.cs' before `partial class UserControl1`:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
[ProgId("Transporter.UserControl1")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[Guid("12fC4E0E-DC1E-A5dc-912B-A631740FG63A")]  // generate your own one!
[ComVisible(true)]
```

Then add these two members to your `UserControl1` class:

```
    ///<summary>
    ///Register the class as a control and set its CodeBase entry
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="key">The registry key of the control</param>
    [ComRegisterFunction()]
    public static void RegisterClass(string key)
    {
        // System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Registered!");
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Called to unregister the control
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="key">The registry key</param>
    [ComUnregisterFunction()]
    public static void UnregisterClass(string key)
    {
        // System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Unregistered!");
    }
```

Finally, add the function you wish to call:

```
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public int StartRequest(string baseAddress, string content, string token, string userName, string password)
    {
        int returnCode = 0;

        // do something here

        return returnCode;
    }
```

Note that there are more differences between a .NET class library and an unmanaged C++ COM DLL (.ocx) as win32 and .NET are completely different ecosystems. For example you would register the component using `regasm.exe` instead of using `regsrv32.exe`.

For a detailed example on how to call `StartRequest()` programatically, have a look at the lower half of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47050380/1284927 (This is MFC 9.0 code, but should also work with MFC 6.0.)

Comment: Thanks @thomiel, I'll try it out. Under what circumstance I need to use LoadLibrary?

Comment: @Ives Do use `LoadLibrary()` if you want to access a win32 dll from win32 code. (MFC is just a wrapper around the win32 API.)